# Detect scroll end event when calling scrollTo on ScrollView

Tags: react-native

I have a simple horizontal slider built using the `ScrollView` component. There is a button to go to the next slide and when pressed I call `scrollTo` method on that `ScrollView` component. I also need to detect when the scroll is finished to display some other animations. I tried using `onMomentumScrollEnd` and `onScrollEndDrag` callbacks but on android neither of them is called when I use `scrollTo` method. Is there any other way to detect scroll 'end' event?

Here is simple example on snack: https://snack.expo.io/@levani/forlorn-bacon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution, i've modified your [snack](https://snack.expo.io/wJtssU!Ft)

I've used `onSroll` listener with the function :

```js
 const scrollDirection = (event) => {
    const offsetX = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x
    const dif = offsetX - (offset || 0);  
    console.log('dif',dif) 
    if (dif == 200) {
      alert('destination reached')
    } 

    setOffset(offsetX);

  };
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: You'r welcome, if you consider its a solution for your problem please check answer. Thanks